# is there a way to remove the select count(*) from this sql statement and logic

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, performance

I have some C++ code that updates a column when a row exists otherwise does nothing. here is what my code looks like now and the select count(*) takes about 15-20 secs. i would like to make this code more efficient.

**RunUpdateLockAliveTimeStamp**

```
  sCommand << "update APP_CC_LOCKS set ALIVETIMESTAMP = ";
  sCommand << " SYSTIMESTAMP(7)";
  sCommand << " where TRANSACTIONID = ?";
```

**RunSelectCountDataCubeLock**

```
  sCommand << "select count(*) from APP_CC_LOCKS";
  sCommand << " where (((SCENARIOID=? and YEARID=? and ENTITYID=? and PARENTID=? and VALUEID=?) and (LOCKTYPE = ?)) or (LOCKTYPE = ?)) and (TRANSACTIONID != ?) and ((TIMEINSERTED < (select MAX(TIMEINSERTED) from APP_CC_LOCKS ";
  sCommand << " where TRANSACTIONID = ?)) or ((TIMEINSERTED = (select MAX(TIMEINSERTED) from ";
  sCommand << “ APP_CC_LOCKS where TRANSACTIONID = ?)) and TRANSACTIONID <= ?))";
```

**Main**

```
        DWORD dwIterationNumber = 0;

        // trying to accquire lock
        cStartTime = DateTimeUtil::currentDateTimeAsMilliseconds();

        while (bLockWasAcquired == false)
        {
              // try to accquire lock
              numBlockingRecords = -1;

              hr = cAccessor.RunSelectCountDataCubeLock(csTransID, lScenario, lYear, lEntity, lParent, lValue, &numBlockingRecords);
              xfm_throw_propagate(FAILED(hr), hr);

              // There's no block record then lock is temporary accquired until we resolve collision
              if (numBlockingRecords == 0)
              {
                    // The lock is now accquired
                    bLockWasAcquired = true;
                    break;
              }

              if (dwIterationNumber > g_lNumIterBeforeUpdatingTimeStamp)
              {
                    //csSQLCmd.clear();
                    hr = cAccessor.RunUpdateLockAliveTimeStamp(csTransID);
                    xfm_throw_propagate(FAILED(hr), hr);
              }
        }
```

Comment: You can probably create a query that takes less time.  Please edit your question, describe what the query is doing, and show the full query in the question.

Comment: Agreed, a nice formatted SQL query rather than some string concatenation commands would be easier to read.

Comment: Do you actually *need* the count itself? Or do you just need to know if either count is zero (nothings there) or count is greater than zero (somethings there)? If the latter, then a quick-fix might be to add `and rownum <= 1` to the counting query. That will allow the optimizer just to pick a "random" row fullfilling the predicates (whichever is the fastest it can get) and just count that one row (if it is there.) Your `numBlockingRecords` will then be either 0 or 1. You might make a better logic by some more rewriting, but the quickfix might help here and now. Or clean up old lock rows?

Answer (score 2):

I dont' think the `count(*)` is what's making the query slow, but rather the two sub selects being performed inside the `where` clause.

```
...((TIMEINSERTED < (select MAX(TIMEINSERTED) from APP_CC_LOCKS where TRANSACTIONID = ?))    
or ((TIMEINSERTED = (select MAX(TIMEINSERTED) from APP_CC_LOCKS where TRANSACTIONID = ?))
```

could be replaced with a single sub select:

```
((TIMEINSERTED <= (select MAX(TIMEINSERTED) from APP_CC_LOCKS where TRANSACTIONID = ?))
```

which will probably half the execution time.

Comment: Just one point - no, `count(col)` is *not* more efficient than `count(*)`. The `*` in `count(*)` does *not* mean "all columns" like `select *`. The `*` in `count(*)` means "count all rows", where `count(col)` means "count rows where col is not null" and `count(1)` means "count rows where the literal 1 is not null". The best way and most self-documenting is to do `count(*)` as it tells both the optimizer and anyone reading the code that you want to "count all rows".

Comment: @KimBergHansen thanks for that very useful information. I guess I simply confused recommendations not to do unnecessary `select *` with doing `count(*)`. Have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It is a very very common misunderstanding, you are not the only one ;-)